# Loop creating indiced of tree branches

Tags: python, tree

How can a loop be implemented in Python which returns the indices of tree branches and where the number of tree branches per layer depth grows by the layer depth to the power of n? n and the *layer depth* shall both be integer numbers.

E.g. for n=2 and this would yield for the first three layers the following number of tree branches (the indices are given in the black boxes):

Layer depth 0: 2**0=1

Layer depth 1: 2**1=2

Layer depth 2: 2**2=4

[image]

E.g. for n=3 and this would yield for the first three layers the following number of tree branches (the indices are given in the black boxes):

Layer depth 0: 3**0=1

Layer depth 1: 3**1=3

Layer depth 2: 3**2=9

[image]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, your images do not match what you say. According to how the number of branches should progress (`depth**layer`), in the first image e.g. you would expect `2**3 = 8` branches in total in the third layer. But in the image there are 16. So either the image is wrong, or the formula. It would make more sense intuitively if the formula `depth**layer` would give you the number of branches *per branch* and not the total number of branches *per layer*. I guess the former is what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following generator produces what your images show:

```
def branching(n, depth):
    yield '1'
    if depth >= 1:
        branches = []
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            branches.append(f'1.{i}')
            yield branches[-1]
    for layer in range(2, depth + 1):
        branches_new = []
        for branch in branches:
            for i in range(1, n**(layer - 1) + 1):
                branches_new.append(f'{branch}.{i}')
                yield branches_new[-1]
            branches = branches_new
```

This

```
for branch in branching(2, 3):
    print(branch)
```

produces

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.2.1
1.2.2
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.2.1
1.1.2.2
1.1.2.3
1.1.2.4
1.2.1.1
1.2.1.2
1.2.1.3
1.2.1.4
1.2.2.1
1.2.2.2
1.2.2.3
1.2.2.4
```

and this for `branching(3, 3)` the output looks like

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.2.1
1.2.2
1.2.3
1.3.1
1.3.2
1.3.3
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.6
1.1.1.7
1.1.1.8
1.1.1.9
...
1.3.3.1
1.3.3.2
1.3.3.3
1.3.3.4
1.3.3.5
1.3.3.6
1.3.3.7
1.3.3.8
1.3.3.9
```

But I'm a bit under the impression that your formulaic description is not quite aligned with the images?

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! Somehow, I've struggled with this :) ... and sorry for the formualic description ... non-naitve speker here ;)